# Using the off-canvas dialog, how can I submit and close it, without redirect?

Tags: 9

I use this as link:

```
<a
  class="use-ajax"           
  data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800}" 
  data-dialog-renderer="off_canvas" 
  data-dialog-type="dialog" 
  href="/group/1/content/create/group_node%3Apage"
>
  Create page
</a>
```

When submitting the page, I like the dialog to close without redirecting the new page created.

How can this be accomplished?
If I add ?destination= with the current URL, then the URL of the off-canvas page is used, not the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Ajax callback to the submit button:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::ajaxCloseForm',
  ],
];
```

Which sends a CloseDialogCommand:

```
/**
 * AJAX callback to close the off-canvas dialog
 */
public function ajaxCloseForm(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new CloseDialogCommand('#drupal-off-canvas'));
  return $response;
}
```

You can also add additional Ajax commands to update the DOM of the page to see the effect of the submit without reloading the page.